How to add serial number in table of content by using conf-abstract templet (overleaf)
In order to prepare Book of Abstracts for an International conference, I used the following code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.25cm,innermargin=2.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{amscd,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{needspace,graphics,graphicx,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{mathtool}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex[intoc]

\newenvironment{conf-abstract}[4][]{
    \needspace{10\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        { \renewcommand\textsuperscript[1]{}
            \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}
            {\texorpdfstring{#2 \newline\emph{#3}}{#2 #3}}
        }
        {{\large\bfseries #2}\marginnote{#1}\par}
        \medskip
        {#3\par}
        \smallskip
        {\small #4\par}
    \end{center}
}{%
    \bigskip
    \hrule
    \bigskip
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\indexauthors}[1]{%
    \forcsvlist{\index}{#1}
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\title{International Conference on Recent Developments in Pure and Applied Mathematics \\ (IRDPAM 2025)}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{List of Abstracts}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
     \begin{conf-abstract}[optional text going into the margin note]
        {Title of Paper - I}
         {Authors (use \textsuperscript as institution markers)}
         {Institutions (use \textsuperscript as institution markers)}
         \indexauthors{Lastname1!Firstname 1, Lastname2!Firstname2}
         Abstract text
         \end{conf-abstract}
         \begin{conf-abstract}[optional text going into the margin note]
            {Title of Paper - II}
            {Authors (use \textsuperscript as institution markers)}
            {Institutions (use \textsuperscript as institution markers)}
            \indexauthors{Lastname1!Firstname 1, Lastname2!Firstname2}
            Abstract text
         \end{conf-abstract}
         \begin{conf-abstract}[optional text going into the margin note]
            {Title of Paper - III}
            {Authors (use \textsuperscript as institution markers)}
            {Institutions (use \textsuperscript as institution markers)}
            \indexauthors{Lastname1!Firstname 1, Lastname2!Firstname2}
            Abstract text
         \end{conf-abstract}
            \renewcommand{\indexname}{Author Index}
        \printindex
\end{document}  

After compiling the above, we get the table of content without serial number for list of abstracts and the rest are place perfectly. Kindly, help us to add serial number in the toc

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please try to make your question clear and simple by providing a minimal working example.

Could you also include an example of a CSV file from which you'd like to extract the serial number?

Minimal working example is given but i don't know how upload output pdf
